# how to put a cite in the same line of a section

Tags: sectioning, citing, inline

i can't put in the same line the title of the section with the number of a reference.

**input**:

\section{Introduzione} \cite{135431}

**output**:

1  Introduzione

[8]

**desired output**:

1  Introduzione [8]

**i don't want to use this**:

\section{Introduzione \cite{135431}}

How can i fix it?
Thanks

PS: i want to avoid this
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please elaborate on why you're against `\section{Introduzione \cite{135431}}`. Would you also be against `\section{Introduzione\quad\mdseries\normalsize\cite{135431}}`?

Comment: thanks for the answer, i modify the question to make more clear the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this answer in [TEXFAQ](http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-runheadtoobig) say:

```
\section[short title]{full title}
```

*If the ‹short title› is present, it is used both for the table of contents and for the page heading.*

In your case:

```
\section[Introduzione]{Introduzione \cite{135431}}
```

Comment: you are my savior thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

One can work with `\if`s and `\protect`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{headings}
\newif\ifConditionalCitation
\newcommand\ConditionalCitation[1]{\ifConditionalCitation#1\fi}
\begin{document}
\ConditionalCitationtrue
\section{Introduzione\protect\ConditionalCitation{\quad\cite{135431}}}
\ConditionalCitationfalse

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
 \bibitem{135431} Albert Einstein 
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]